# Does browser send a get request to fetch local files?

Tags: django, http, tcp

When I open a directory in Chrome such as:

```
file:///Users/me/desktop/
```

Does the chrome send a get request to OS to fetch the file?

Comment: It's not clear what you wanted to achieve. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I rewrite my question @RajaSimon

Comment: No. It does not issue a `GET`. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03#section-3.1